# Unable to Store Data into persistent store after LightWeight migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

old structure of core data model

Student -- > name

Updated structure of model ( after lightweight migration)

Student --> name , rollNumber

here student is entity and name and rollNumber is attribute.

I am using sqlite db for persitent

**problem** :

As old db have only 1 column name when i insert new record it will give error model not match. is core data update table structure automatic in lightweight migration. or i need to remove database.

Comment: Did you create a new model version, or just edit the existing model file?

Comment: i have created new model version based on existing model